# Java scanning text file incorrectly from network drive

Tags: java, text-files, java.util.scanner, network-drive

I have an 18,000 line text file that I am scanning from a mapped network drive. I am using the scanner class in Java. When the file is stored on my local machine, my code confirms that it has 18,000 lines via a line counter variable. Using the same code, but only changing the file path of the text file to the network drive, it returns ~700 lines. Does anyone know why this might be happening? When I drag the file from network drive to C, it returns 700, but when I copy the contents and put it in a new file in C drive, it returns the true number of lines. My code is below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        File text = new File("C:\\Users\\textfile.txt"); //returns correct number of lines
        //File text = new File("N:\\textfile.txt"); //returns incorrect number of lines
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(text);
        int linecount = 0;
        while(scan.hasNextLine())
        {
            linecount++;
            scan.nextLine();
        }
        scan.close();
        System.out.println(linecount);
    }
```

Comment: It's got nothing to do with java. Or at least, nothing to do with the code you pasted; it's fine.

Comment: @rzwitserloot I know, just figured I would include the language and the code being used for the full picture

Comment: What is the size, in bytes, of the file on the C: drive?  What is the size, in bytes, of the file on the N: drive?

Comment: @VGR Both are same size: 1,248,212 bytes

Comment: See what happens when you do it like this: `import java.nio.file.Files;import java.nio.file.Path;import java.io.InputStream;public class LineCounter {public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {try(InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(Path.of("N:/textfile.txt"))) {int count = 0;int buf = -1;while ((buf = in.read()) > -1) {if (buf == '\n') {count++;}}System.out.printf("File contains %d line(s)%n", count);}}}`

Comment: This is really strange. I created a text file with 18,000 lines and 1.24 MB size in a network drive (Z:) but could not reproduce the issue. Your code just gives the correct line number.

Comment: @g00se that code counted it correctly!

Comment: @g00se Thank you so much.. I ended up using input stream in conjunction with scanner to perform the operations I needed to.

Comment: That's OK - as long as you don't use it as a universal solution to line counting as there might be the occasional early/exotic text file for which that won't work